# I want to show a video or Lottie animation for my React Weather App

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner who is learning react.js and I have made a Weather app through [React JS Tutorial – Build a Weather App With Cities Autocomplete](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Reny0cTTv24&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org) and now I want to add my lottie animation to appear when a user visits and after the lottie animation goes after 4 seconds then the content of the application appears. Please help me achieve this.

Thank you

I tried to create another component VideoPlayer.jsx and then put the lottie on it and then added a variable and used useEffect:

```
const VideoPlayer = ({ onVideoEnd }) => {
  const [videoLoaded, setVideoLoaded] = useState(false);


  useEffect(() => {
    const handleVideoLoad = () => {
      setVideoLoaded(true);
    };

    const handleVideoEnded = () => {
      if (onVideoEnd) {
        onVideoEnd();
      }
    };

    const videoElement = document.getElementById('myVideo');
    videoElement.addEventListener('loadeddata', handleVideoLoad);
    videoElement.addEventListener('ended', handleVideoEnded);

    return () => {
      videoElement.removeEventListener('loadeddata', handleVideoLoad);
      videoElement.removeEventListener('ended', handleVideoEnded);
    };
  }, [onVideoEnd]);
```

give it an absolute position and z-index of 1000.

In the return, i added

```
{!videoLoaded && <p>Loading video...</p>}
<video id="myVideo" width="100%" height="100%" autoPlay muted>
        <source src="lottie.json" type="lottie/json" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Lottie

It would be easier and more efficient to use a Lottie animation. Consider using a lottie library which will do all the heavy lifting for you. I found https://www.npmjs.com/package/lottie-react very easy to use in my projects.

Here is an example from the npm link on how to use it https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/lottie-react-component-2k13t?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.tsx

### Rendering a lottie while the app renders

I suggest rendering a lottie animation while you are fetching data from an API, artificially slowing down the APP, might not be ok. I also provided an example where your user will artificially wait 4 seconds and look at your lottie animation and then the app will render

```js
const App = () => {
// if you use custom hooks, usually you will have a loading state
const {isFetching, weatherData, error } = useAxiosGet(someWeatherAPI)

// show the user the loading animation
if (isFetching)
 {
  return <Lottie animationData={groovyWalkAnimation} loop />
 }
 return <div>{weatherData}</div>
}
```

Example where the user waits 4 seconds

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Lottie from 'react-lottie'
// TODO: import your JSON animation
import groovyWalkAnimation from './path_to_your_animation.json'

const App = () => {
 const [isAppRendered, setIsAppRendered] = useState(false)
 const {isFetching, weatherData, error } = useAxiosGet(someWeatherAPI)


 useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setIsAppRendered(true)
    }, 4000); // Wait 4 seconds

    // Clean up the timer on unmount
    return () => clearTimeout(timer)
 }, [])

 // We want to make sure the API has responded 
 // with data before we render the data
 if (isAppRendered && !isFetching) {
    return <div>{weatherData}</div>
 }

 return (
    <Lottie
      // TODO: Add custom styling for the width and height
      animationData={groovyWalkAnimation}
      loop
    />
 )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, it worked!